# Dynamics of Gyroscopic P recession

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gyroscopes, precession

It is taught relatively early in classical mechanics that the precession of a top exists because when the body is spinning, the gravitation torque pushes the rotational axis (more accurately it pushes the angular momentum vector) and thus rotates the torque creating a precession.  I have been working on deriving the exact equations which govern a top or gyroscope for some time, however, I'm not confident in my derivation or in my results, although they seem plausible, so can someone please supply a derivation for the equations of motion $ (\theta(t),\phi(t))$ for a gyroscope whose rotating element (preferably a disk) follows a function $\omega(t)$. I want to use the angular velocity function to model the environmental slow down on the rotation and the eventual fall of the object. [[image: Yes, the picture says <span class=]$\theta$ constant, but i'm interested in the case where it isn't.">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu5fX.png)

Comment: See equations (27), (28), and (29) in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/00ad/ce3ea858d74a8befa7f9743963586405fda3.pdf

Comment: Also note how two of the second-order equations reduce to first-order ones, in (40) and (41).

Comment: The source mentioned by G.Smith should be sufficient for your purpose. Other than that: as we know, friction drains energy, and the gyroscope sags down. The slower the spin rate the faster the corresponding precessing motion. As the gyroscope sags down potential energy is converted to kinetic energy required for the precessing motion. In real world application I suspect friction at the pivot (purple in the image) is a larger contribution than air friction. I tried a gyroscope setup on a rotating table thus avoiding pivot point friction; that resulted in slower decay.